# How to make clone div enabled using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, web-deployment

[This is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kIYj.png)

I have been trying to enabled my coned div and disable parent div  .

```
function AddGroup() {
var newgrouplist = $("#group-list-edit-1").clone();
number1 = number1 +1 ;
newgrouplist.attr("id", "group-list-edit-"+number1);
newgrouplist.find("#group_select_1").attr("id", "group_select_"+number1);
newgrouplist.find("#group_select_1").attr("class", "group_select_clone");
$('.group_select_clone1').attr("enabled", "true");  
newgrouplist.find("#del_div").attr("style","border: 1px solid;font-size: 16px;padding: 1px;");
newgrouplist.find("#del_div").attr("onclick","DelGroup('group-list-edit-"+number1+"');");
//append clone on the end
```

This is how i'm editing my clone. Is there anyone who can help me with my problem ?

Comment: Also provide html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.clone()` method.

Comment: var newgrouplist = $("#group-list-edit-1").clone();

Comment: Here I had used .clone and clone is going correctly . In current time my clone is working but now I am clone with <a disable="true"> and when I clone it I get <a disable="true "> but actually I need <a enabled ="true "> when I clone the div but parents div must be <a disabled="true"> Can you help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `.clone()` method. However, the problem statement is not clear even with the help of a screenshot. Could you create a sample codes in jsfiddle replicating the problem?